# Prevent QChart PlotArea shifting after axis labels values changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyside

When you zoom the plot, axis values labels changes and increase their length like:
`5.0->5.01->5.001->5.0001 etc`. This cause next behaviour:

1. Vertical axis shifts in horizontal direction every time value label append digit in itself. This cause the whole plot area shifting. Looks kinda 'unstable'.
2. Too much zoom cause too long values. This cause lag and continues disfunction of zoom.

It's not possible to fix the second problem with `y_axis.setLabelFormat('%d') because i can't just cut off values. I need to display them in necessary value-gap.

So, the main idea is to force chart to draw plotArea, which is already shifted enough, to fit maximum length of axis label. And to prevent shifting even here, we need to stop zooming plot area when we reach some length of the axis labels. So, it will look like this: [image].

Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PySide6.QtCharts import QChart, QChartView, QLineSeries, QValueAxis


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("GeeksCoders LineChart Example")

        # Create the main widget and layout
        widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)

        # Create the chart view and add it to the layout
        chart_view = QChartView()
        chart_view.setRubberBand(QChartView.RectangleRubberBand)

        chart_view.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        layout.addWidget(chart_view)

        # Create the chart and add it to the view
        chart = QChart()
        chart.setTitle("GeeksCoders Monthly Sales")
        chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)

        # Add data to the chart
        series = QLineSeries()
        series.setName("Sales Data")
        sales_data = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65]
        months = range(1, 13)
        for i in range(12):
            series.append(months[i], sales_data[i])
        chart.addSeries(series)

        # Add axes to the chart
        axis_x = QValueAxis()
        axis_x.setLabelFormat("%i")
        axis_x.setTitleText("Month")
        chart.addAxis(axis_x, Qt.AlignBottom)
        series.attachAxis(axis_x)

        axis_y = QValueAxis()
        axis_y.setLabelFormat("%i")
        axis_y.setTitleText("Sales")
        chart.addAxis(axis_y, Qt.AlignLeft)
        series.attachAxis(axis_y)

        # Set the chart view's chart
        chart_view.setChart(chart)
        coordinates = chart.plotArea().getCoords()
        chart.plotArea().setCoords(300, coordinates[1], coordinates[2], coordinates[3])
        # Set the central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

In 'Green right' example we need to force axes labels to expand outside plotArea, instead of 'Red' inside expansion. And we need to prevent too deep zoom. If we reach some digits count in label we stop zooming.

As example, `setFormat('%.3f')` doesn't help, because we just don't show the full labels, but we still zooming and real values expand.

**UPD:** Thanks to @relent95, it's possible to fix plotArea left border with setting plotArea manually. But, it affects the whole chartView. Resizing doesn't work anymore. And plot area unattaches from the background. Using `setPlotArea(Qrect(300, 0, 0, 0))` to set only left border doesn't help. Behaviour in this case looks like with `QRect(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Here is the code updates:

```
class CustomChartView(QChartView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def set_plot_once(self):
        old_plot_area = self.chart().plotArea()
        # self.chart().setPlotArea(QRect(300, 0, 0, 0))  # causes default behaviour without shifting
        self.chart().setPlotArea(QRect(300, old_plot_area.y(), old_plot_area.width(), old_plot_area.height()))  
        # This method causes fixed sizes without resizing

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
        ...
        self.chart_view.setChart(chart)
        self.chart_view.set_plot_once()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

Comment: Post a [mre]. Anyway, what did you try? Why not calculate proper coordinates for what you want and set the plotting area manually with the ```setPlotArea()```?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add resizing rubberband in example. Now example is fixed. In case setting plotArea manualy, i think the result will be the same. I've tried to implement custom ChartView and recreated mouseReleaseEvent, so, after every resizing i recalculate the plotArea rectangle, but somehow it use it's own size, with labels shifting. May be i've got wrong understanding of your idea. What should i implement?

Comment: You did ```chart.plotArea().setCoords(...)```, which does not update the chart, because you only modified a temporary object(```QRectF```). Try the ```setPlotArea()``` as I said.

Comment: @relent95, Thank you a lot!!! In my previous attempt i messed with functions calling. Now your advice works great. As minimum as left border stays fixed. But here are some issues, like unavailable resizing etc. I described this in post update. I'll really appreciate any help there too.